# Array of multicharacter character constat and convert it to char *

Tags: c, char, character

How to properly declare an array in C with multicharacter character like '⅓','⅔','⅕','⅖','⅗', and then convert one of those values into char *?

Comment: By multi character you mean UTF-8?

Comment: `char *` is not able to represent more than 256 distinct characters in any given codepage, unless it contains a string that has been encoded as a sequence of bytes (such as the UTF-8 encoding).  It sounds like you want a wide string (`wchar_t *`).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure, I just retyped warning from console. 
I will try rewrite code with wchar_t right now and check the result.

Comment: Multi-character constants are not a useful feature of C; they're certainly not the way to store non-ASCII UTF-8 characters. You want *wide characters* for this purpose. But you still can't convert a character *value* to a *pointer to such a value*.

Comment: Maybe I should put it into context. I've got ready library with function that I need to show text on screen. One of his parameters is char * c, and when I run this function with e.g. MyMagicFunction("⅓"); everything is fine, but I need all signs in another type than char *, because it takes to much space.

Comment: Too much space? How much space?